# Select row depending upon different condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

My source table looks something like below
[image]

This is the intermediate step
[image]

And the final output should look like below
[image]

Basically first I need to `SELECT` the lowest `Rank` for a `PERSONID`, `AddressID` and `PhoneType`. If there are multiple rows with the same `Rank`, then I need to return which ever has the max `VerificationDate` and then get the final output.

Create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE AddressPhone ([PERSONID] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
                           [AddressID] [int] NOT NULL,
                           [PhoneType] [varchar](2) NOT NULL,
                           [PhoneNumber] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
                           [VerificationDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
                           [Rank] [int] NOT NULL) ON [PRIMARY];
```

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: New to this forum so finding it extremely difficult to format text which is understandable. I have tried using the help but havn't been successful when trying to create a table with data

Comment: SO is rubbish with tables, but there are [generators](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) to help with that.

Comment: The trick to formatting is to copy/paste those tables results and indent each row by 4.  It's a hassle and never looks very good.  But even better, if you script out the SQL that would create those tables, and script the inserts to populate the data people can just run it to get the sample data on their own computer.

Comment: When editing, write the values in proper columns. Then mark the text and click `{}`.

Comment: You also might like to anonimize those phone numbers.

Comment: Comments don't accept formatted text. You need to put the data in your question by [editting](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51789178/edit) it. I've done this for you for your `CREATE` statement (and fixed the syntax errors), however, please make sure you do this for your `INSERT` statement.

Comment: @Sunil What have you tried so far???  Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

Sample data (**not the same, but it is equivalent**):

```
declare @tbl table (personid int, addressid int, phonetype bit, phonenumber int, verificationdate date, rank int);
insert into @tbl values
(1, 1, 0, null, '2014-06-24', 4),
(1, 1, 1, null, '2014-06-24', 4),
(1, 1, 1, null, '2014-06-24', 4),
(1, 1, 1, null, '2014-06-24', 4),
(1, 1, 1, null, '2014-06-24', 4),
(1, 1, 0, null, '2014-06-24', 4),
(1, 1, 0, null, '2014-06-24', 3),
(1, 1, 0, null, '2014-06-24', 4),
(1, 1, 1, null, '2014-06-24', 2),
(1, 1, 1, null, '2014-06-24', 1),
(1, 1, 0, null, '2014-06-24', 4),
(1, 1, 1, null, '2014-06-24', 4),

(2, 2, 0, null, '2014-06-24', 2),
(2, 2, 0, null, '2014-06-24', 1),
(2, 2, 0, null, '2014-06-24', 4),
(2, 2, 1, null, '2014-06-25', 1),
(2, 2, 1, null, '2014-06-24', 1);

--intermediate step
select personid, addressid, phonetype, phonenumber, verificationdate, rank,
       row_number() over (partition by rank order by verificationdate) rnVerDate
from (
    select personid, addressid, phonetype, phonenumber, verificationdate, rank,
           row_number() over (partition by personid, addressid, phonetype order by rank desc) rnRank
    from @tbl
) a where rnRank = 1

--final result
select personid, addressid, phonetype, phonenumber, verificationdate, rank
from (
    select personid, addressid, phonetype, phonenumber, verificationdate, rank,
           row_number() over (partition by rank order by verificationdate) rnVerDate
    from (
        select personid, addressid, phonetype, phonenumber, verificationdate, rank,
               row_number() over (partition by personid, addressid, phonetype order by rank desc) rnRank
        from @tbl
    ) a where rnRank = 1
) a where rnVerDate = 1
```

Comment: Hi Michal. Thanks for the query but I am not getting the desired output. The output that I get is of the below columns and not as the final output above    PERSONID, ADDRESSID, PHONETYPE,PHONENUMBER,VERIFICATION DATE, RANK    and I am getting only one record for a PERSONID ADDRESSID COMBINATION

Comment: When I change rank desc to rank asc in the above query then for one PERSONID ADDRESSID combination I get two records one with Rank 1 and one with rank 4 but when it was desc I was getting only one record with rank 4

Comment: @Sunil I am getting correct result with your data. Anyway, if answer helped you you should accept it :)

Comment: Oh Michal definitely your query helped me. There is no denying the fact. I accept that and I am thankful to you for the same.

Comment: @Sunil I am happy that I could help. I meant accepting by checking green mark left to the answer :)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn `I meant accepting by checking green mark` ha! I love it :) :)  You've earned my upvote!

Comment: @Michal I would not mind checking the green mark however I would not like to sound rude. If you see the 3 pictures above the middle one is what we have got after I make the changes to the query as below. However I am not getting 2 rows for second section in the sample you provided above.

Comment: rows for second section in the sample you provided above.   select personid, addressid, phonetype, phonenumber, verificationdate, rank from (
    select personid, addressid, phonetype, phonenumber, verificationdate, rank, row_number() over (partition by rank order by verificationdate) rnVerDate  from ( select personid, addressid, phonetype, phonenumber, verificationdate, rank, row_number() over (partition by personid, addressid, phonetype order by rank desc) rnRank from @tbl ) a where rnRank = 1
) a where rnVerDate = 1

Comment: The query works exactly as supposed to, I tested it. You might have wrong types somewhere. Are you sure that `verificationdate` has `datetime` type? It doesn't look like it.

Comment: It is datetime I checked my database. The excel did not format it correctly. Wish I could somehow contact you :)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn let me explain in detail with the sample data you gave. From the first set I should get two records PERSONID - 1, ADRESSID - 1, phonetype - 0, phone number - null, verification date - 2014-06-24, rank- 3 and the other record from the first set PERSONID - 1, ADRESSID - 1, phonetype - 1, phone number - null, verification date - 2014-06-24, rank- 1

Comment: @MichałTurczyn from the second set it would be PERSONID - 2, ADRESSID - 2, phonetype - 0, phone number - null, verification date - 2014-06-24, rank- 1 and the second record should be PERSONID - 2, ADRESSID - 2, phonetype - 1, phone number - null, verification date - 2014-06-25, rank- 1. Please let me know if you agree to this

Comment: @MichałTurczyn after getting these 4 record sets I need to convert it to 2 record set  as .  PERSONID - 1, ADRESSID - 1, Phone Nimnber - null, FaxNumber - null, Rank- 1,3 and the other record being  PERSONID - 2, ADRESSID - 2, hone Nimnber - null, FaxNumber - null, Rank- 1,1

Comment: The inner query returns intermediate step and outer returns the final result. See updated answer with details.